# Sending a file with OBEX push in Python

Tags: python, bluetooth, obex

How to send a file using OBEX push to a device, which has an open OBEX port in Python? In my case it is a Bluetooth device.

Answer (score 0):

There is an "[OBEX data server](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/obex-data-server)" DEBIAN package with DBus interface which could help you. Accessing DBus through Python is fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/

The documentation for the OBEX client is here: http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/doc/lightblue.obex-OBEXClient.html